# Не меняется цвет лэйбла(радиобаттон) при :checked!

Tags: html, css

Делаю слайдер с помощью CSS: радиобаттоны + к ним лейблы(чтобы, через них стилизовать). Все работает - слайды переключаются при :checked. Но все лейблы выглядят одинаково. А надо чтобы при :checked так же менялся цвет лейбла. Не могу это реализовать! Прошу помощи! Код:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

label {
    background: #9A6400;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    transition: .5s;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#btn1:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn1:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 200%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn2:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
} 

#btn2:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn3:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: -200%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn3:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="button" id="btn1" checked>
              <input type="radio" name="button" id="btn2">
              <input type="radio" name="button" id="btn3">
              
              <label for="btn1"></label>
              <label for="btn2"></label>
              <label for="btn3"></label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

#btn1:checked ~ label[for="btn1"] {
background-color: red;
}

#btn2:checked ~ label[for="btn2"] {
background-color: red;
}

#btn3:checked ~ label[for="btn3"] {
background-color: red;
}

label {
    background: #9A6400;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    transition: .5s;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#btn1:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn1:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 200%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn2:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
} 

#btn2:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn3:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: -200%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#btn3:checked ~ #slides .articles article:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="button" id="btn1" checked>
              <input type="radio" name="button" id="btn2">
              <input type="radio" name="button" id="btn3">
              
              <label for="btn1"></label>
              <label for="btn2"></label>
              <label for="btn3"></label>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все работает!

Comment: @АлдиярЕсентаев, если Вас устраивает ответ, то поставьте галочку слева от ответа, это поможет людям в будущем с идентичной проблемой.